# Can we use Google Analytics (GA4 version) for an intranet?

Tags: google-analytics

When I try to set up a 'web site' property, it asks for the website URL - but this site is not available on the internet so Google Analytics' servers won't be able to contact the site- will this prevent GA4 working, or can we just put our default company website url in, even though it won't be that site we are reporting on in this instance.